# Failing to catch empty string with if statement

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Having some trouble with Javascript values in a Lightning Component Controller/Helper.

This function is part of a form. Before submission, it goes over required fields and checks if they're empty so it can decide whether or not to submit. Here's the code in question:

```
outer:
        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            inner:
            for(var j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++){
                var req = list[i][j]['required'];
                if (req) {
                    var val = list[i][j]['val'];
                    // This 'if' is the offender:
                    if ((val==''||val==' '||val.length==0||val==undefined||val==null) && val!=0) {
                        valid = false;
                        console.log('VALUE \''+val+'\' INVALID @ '+i+':'+j);
                        break outer;
                    } else {
                        console.log('TEMP1: '+i+':'+j+':'+val);
                        console.log('TEMP2: '+(typeof val));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What this if statement is supposed to do is check for empty fields, while allowing zero values (because zeroes are valid answers). Val may be a string or a number when it comes through.

Here's the output during runtime:

```
TEMP1: 3:2:10000
TEMP2: number
TEMP1: 3:3:10000
TEMP2: number
TEMP1: 3:6:
TEMP2: string
TEMP1: 3:7:
TEMP2: string
TEMP1: 3:10:
TEMP2: string
TEMP1: 3:11:1
TEMP2: number
TEMP1: 3:12:Yes
TEMP2: string
TEMP1: 3:13:1000
TEMP2: number
TEMP1: 3:14:50
TEMP2: number
TEMP1: 3:15:55
TEMP2: number
```

As you can see, the output for indeces 6, 7, and 10 output empty strings in console, but that is somehow not caught by the if statement above? What value could `val` have that allows it to skip that if statement but still print out that empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is that in JavaScript following statement is true:

```
 (0 == '')
```

In your scenario, if val is empty string, then in condition

```
((val == ''|| val == ' ' || val.length == 0 || val == undefined || val == null ) && val != 0)
```

last operand will be evaluated as false, since **0, '', null** are equal using '**==**' operator.

To make it working, it will be better to use '===' (strict comparison). For example:

```
if ((val==='' || val===' '|| val.length===0 || val == null ) && val !== 0 )
```

Nice links to read:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: This is definitely what I needed to see. I guess I didn't know what I didn't know about JS boolean expressions. Of course, after fixing this line, I had to go through and start fixing the other checks I make in order to resolve my values through-and-through.

The fact that `(0=='')` blows my mind.

Comment: FWIW, aura has some built in utilities that help checking this and improves readability, e.g. `$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull()`, see here http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Util